What the heck is up with odaka patterns in realized speech?
I have been plagued with uncertainty as to whether my ears are hearing a phenomenon that doesn't exist or not. Double negative aside let me get to the point.
Sometimes I hear 明らか [2] and sometimes [3].
Sometimes I hear 賑やか [2] or [3]
Sometimes I hear ～られる\のか or ～られ\るのか for THE SAME VERB (heiban combing with の)
Sometimes I hear ちから\がない or ちか\らがない
There's two things I keep hearing:

something that should be odaka has its accent moved by one, like かが\み[鏡]に写ってる！
something that is nakadaka has its nucleus moved by one　おも\わなかった vs おもわ\なかった

Maybe this never happens and my ears lie. Maybe this is normal... Dunno. There is like NO information on this.
There are so many weird pitch things I've noticed that I've had no one to talk to with... Like how so many katakana words actually are pronounced a certain pitch accent but the dictionary doesn't say so.

あなたたち i hear as [2] or [3]

Did you mean おもわ\なかった vs おもわな\かった?

No no, I don't mishear it as a heiban verb. But sometimes when people say it fast it will sound like the nucleus moves 1 beat earlier (what I wrote).

明らか and にぎやか are not Odaka either way, are they? (I assume [n] refers to the nucleus at n-th mora from the end?) I feel that your question contains multiple phenomena of accent change.

[n] means the nucleus is at the n-th mora as is notated by daijirin dictionary)大辞林 第三版). And yeah they are both nakadaka. I said '2. something that is nakadaka has its nucleus moved by one' as one of my problems for hearing.

Basically I have almost no problem with hearing heiban and atamadaka problems, and haven't for at least a year. However sometimes when spoken fast I feel like odaka patterns shift slightly and same with nakadaka. Another example of a nakadaka pattern changing is ありがとう which i feel like tends to be more [3] than [2] pretty often. Especially ありがとね [3]. I think this is called 遅下がり

おも\わなかった is unlikely but if you hear it in fast speech, it could be that /mowa/ is reduced so much it's pronounced like one long syllable or diphthong with a falling tone. Do you hear this with verbs that don't end with う (わ in their ない-forms)?

I think omowanakatta is just one word that's said frequently enough that i've noticed sometimes it's pronounced kinda weird like that. most of the time i hear verbs normally. I heard earlier today 逃さないで that sounded like right inbetween [3] and [4] but it was sort of emphatic speech

[3] or [4] is OK for 逃さない (or 思わない). You claim you hear [2] for 思わない. My question was, does that happen with other verbs, such as 逃さない.

I don't think I've ever heard that for something like nogasu, or similar verbs. Also [3] or [4] is okay for nogasanai?

I recommend focusing your questions a bit more, as currently you are spending at least half of the words in your question focusing on "pitch is hard and I'm confused" (which is fine but doesn't make for a great question on a Q&A site), and mixing different unrelated phenomenon (which also makes it hard for other people to find and benefit from the question).
That said let me try and go through each thing.

Sometimes I hear 明らか [2] and sometimes [3].
Sometimes I hear 賑やか [2] or [3]
Sometimes I hear ～られる\のか or ～られ\るのか for THE SAME VERB (heiban combing with の)

These are basically all almost certainly just mishearings, so you'd need to provide an audio file if you wanted an analysis on why you might be mishearing it.
It is always あき＼らか and にぎ＼やか and 〜られる＼のか.
For the case where a [2] word sounds like [3] (like 明らか、賑やか for you） you might be experiencing difficultly due to おそ下がり　but it seems you already know about this phenomenon given your comment.
For the られる case, there is no reason to mishear an accent kernel shifting backwards one mora, except maybe if you had learned the wrong pattern very early on (e.g., thinking that it's always られ＼る for all verbs) and haven't been able to break it.

Sometimes I hear ちから\がない or ちか\らがない
something that should be odaka has its accent moved by one, like かが\み[鏡]に写ってる！

Both of these are actual phenomenon, where a 3-letter odaka word is pronounced [2] by some speakers. It depends on the specific word whether it sounds dialectal or not, but for 力 and 鏡 both [2] and [3] sound completely standard these days.

something that is nakadaka has its nucleus moved by one　おも\わなかった vs おもわ\なかった

This is not really a thing with 思わなかった, it is always pronounced 思わ＼なかった so I think you are just mishearing. Please share audio otherwise it's impossible to say more.

Like how so many katakana words actually are pronounced a certain pitch accent but the dictionary doesn't say so.

Yes, this is a problem with dictionaries that the accent for many katakana words has changed and the dictionaries have not caught up.

http://sndup.net/gjb8 初めて [3]
http://sndup.net/pjbs 賑やか [3]
http://sndup.net/cbnz 聞きたかった [4]
https://sndup.net/fxs7/ 賑やか [3] another example

https://sndup.net/kvt9/ 出来事 [3] https://sndup.net/y59w/ すれば sounds like [1] to me

(Aside from the last one) they are basically all cases of おそ下がり, and get auto-repaired to the right location by listeners. 聞きたかった is the only one that stands out to me as being particularly egregious, but it happens occasionally with female speakers.

As for すれば, it can also auto-repaired, and it's sort of like the opposite of おそ下がり and is a bit of intonation happening on top of the pitch accent. The fundamental mechanism is that when a speaker uses extra tension in their voice (either due to extra stress, or excitement etc), the articulation for pitch accent gets a little blurred, but it happens in a way where it doesn't sound like an accent on the wrong mora, but rather just an ambiguous accent which can fall wherever the listener wants it to (i.e., in the right spot, which it's usually centered around).

http://sndup.net/rjky 構わない [2]
構わない sounding more like [2] than [3] i find occurs pretty often... with all these pitch accent irregularities should i purposely correct it in my head or is it okay for me to just like... accept what i hear as what i hear
additionally https://sndup.net/hfbz/ すまない [??]
in relaxed casual speech does it really matter if pitch accent is off by a mora... i mean even voice actors who are focused kinda pronounce pitch accent messily sometimes

http://sndup.net/g73f この星には 星 as [1]...? ive heard smt like この国には with kuni as odaka but smt like this is very perplexing to me... https://sndup.net/gsng/
